# Hashbang with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm looking for having urls like **http://example.org/!#/followers** and **http://example.org/!#/following** in my django application.

All plugin like jquery history plugin, jQuery BBQ and others, teach how to have urls like this **http://example.org/#followers** and **http://example.org/#following**.

I want **!#**, is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It's a perfectly valid question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with jquery-history.

Comment: how did you achieve this with jquery history?? ive been looking for a way to do this for a while

Comment: yea but theres no docs on making it applicable for Google AJAX Crawling methods and i cant seem to figure this one out.. im using jQuery Address ATM and its sprouting all sorts of problems

Comment: Found and excellent source on [how to make ajax content crawlable by google bot?](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

Hash bangs are bad. Bad for your application and [bad for the web](http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs). Use the [pushstate api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate) to achieve the similar effect in supported browsers. You can even use the awesome [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)

The part of the URL that is after # is not even sent to the server. In the page, you hookup the JS to send a AJAX request and load the particular div, from the real URL your server gives that content from.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a clarification ... do you want bang-hash (!#), or hash-bang (#!)? The latter is the common url scheme for AJAX-ified sites that Google uses to index varying states in a web application. However, it isn't something you can build into a Django URL scheme, because the hash signifies to the browser that what follows is a URL fragment, so it doesn't get sent the same way to your Django engine. It's really a structure for javascript (as you point out, jquery) rather than for any sort of backend processing.

Comment: I agree. This sounds like a javascript question. What's the Django connection?