# PushState() PopState() integration

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-history

I have a website that serves content like so, using .js:

```
var FluidNav = {
init: function() {
    $("a[href*=#]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]) {
            FluidNav.goTo($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]);
        }
    });
    this.goTo("home");
},
goTo: function(page) {
    var next_page = $("#"+page);
    var nav_item = $('nav ul li a[href=#'+page+']');
    $("nav ul li").removeClass("current");
    nav_item.parent().addClass("current");
    FluidNav.resizePage((next_page.height() + 40), true, function() {
         $(".page").removeClass("current"); next_page.addClass("current"); 
    });
    $(".page").fadeOut(500);
    next_page.fadeIn(500);

    FluidNav.centerArrow(nav_item);

},
centerArrow: function(nav_item, animate) {
    var left_margin = (nav_item.parent().position().left + nav_item.parent().width()) + 24 - (nav_item.parent().width() / 2);
    if(animate != false) {
        $("nav .arrow").animate({
            left: left_margin - 8
        }, 500, function() { $(this).show(); });
    } else {
        $("nav .arrow").css({ left: left_margin - 8 });
    }
},
resizePage: function(size, animate, callback) {
    if(size) { var new_size = size; } else { var new_size = $(".page.current").height() + 40; }
    if(!callback) { callback = function(){}; }
    if(animate) {
        $("#pages").animate({ height: new_size }, 400, function() { callback.call(); }); 
    } else {
        $("#pages").css({ height: new_size }); 
    }
}};
```

So far so good, but the client wants a browser back button functionality integrated. I did my homework and with the help of SO and other sources found out that the pushState and popState are the best way to achieve this.

If you take a second to read the code above, you will find out the following:

1. If you type website.com/#team in your browser, you are going to get the front page, not the #team page. If you want to navigate to #team, you are going to have to click from there.
2. If you navigate to #team and then want to go back to the front page, and you press the back button, you are going to get redirected to where you were before vising the website. Kicked out so to speak.

This is done with the purpose of a smoother browsing experience.

However, I now need to achieve the following, and I am a bit lost as to what changes I am going to have to make to my .js file above:

1. Achieve a working back-button functionality (manipulate the
   browser's history storage)
2. When I type website.com/#team in the
   URL bar, to go to that page and not the front page.

Here is an example website built with this functionality so you can see how it functions. http://themes.two2twelve.com/site/fluidapp/light/

Comment: In general, I have found any application that changes the behavior of the "back" button to be intensely annoying.

Comment: Maybe you can set up a stripped fiddle? It would help to play around with as the solution is not obvious.

Comment: Could you please specify what a stripped fiddle is? Tried googling it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You might try integrating a library that handles browsers incapable of pushState (fallback to hash urls like you're describing. I've had some luck with [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) in the past. (Get it??)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did the following:

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This answer was provided by the asker as an edit to the question, rather than as an answer. I have moved it here to conform to site standards.

---

I did the following:

1. Download and unzip History.js to my server as instructed here: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/
2. Follow the install here: https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify
3. Installed the StateRouter from here [Can't understand History.js, need it simplified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369043/cant-understand-history-js-need-it-simplified) and here https://github.com/aknuds1/staterouter.js/tree/master/lib

So far what has been achieved:

Now the URLs actually change with the back button, meaning:

I go to **Home -> Users -> Staff** and then using the Back button the URL in the URL bar will change like so: **www.123.com/#staff -> www.123.com/#users -> www.123.com/#home** . However, only the URl changes and not the content. Any ideas what I am missing?