# New page - no ajax? but ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at this page: https://github.com/mozilla/chromeless/tree/master/examples/first_browser

When I browse between the folders and files, my browser changes the complete url. No Hashtag found like in other jQuery-ways. A whole new page..

But how to change the complete Page and not reloading it?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use `pushState` as [described on their blog](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider)

Answer (score 3):

they use this: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Answer (score 2):

This is html5 pushstate. here are a couple of links to explain it further:

- http://yysource.com/2011/07/html5-and-pushstate/
- http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate
- [Good tutorial for using HTML5 History API (Pushstate?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate)