# Open link in modal dialog (like Chrome Web Store)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

How can i open a url link within a modal dialog like on Chrome Web Store when opening a Chrome App. Notice the background ramains in shaddow but it's still the home page. And the URL changes in Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For dialog** use jQuery UI

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message

**For changing URL** with JS use History API

http://html5demos.com/history

Also check [Good tutorial for using HTML5 History API (Pushstate?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015613/656489)

For older browsers you may have to use [location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp), the above jQuery UI site is a good example for this.

For opening all links in a dialog you may code like below

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url=$(this).attr('href')+"?content_only"; //content_only added to tell index.php to give only content without template and JS
   $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('.dialog').html(data).dialog();
   //change URL here
  });
});
```

**For pointing all URLs to homepage** you have to do server side tricks, point all URLs to index.php. Like `example.com/index.php/subpage` and check with on Document ready if the URL is not just `index.php` I mean something like `example.com/index.php/subpage` then open `example.com/index.php/subpage?content_only` in a dialog. In `index.php` use a criterion, `content_only` is specified then return only the content of `subpage` without template and JS.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. but your sugested method does not work entierly becouse when you enter www.demopage.com/example.php in the URL address bar it will open only example.php, without the homepage in the background.

Comment: This thing is a bit tricky and detailed, anyway I have updated the answer.