# add querystring to URL on page load

Tags: jquery, url, checkbox, query-string, checked

The original URL is http://mysite.com/locations.aspx
When someone clicks on Locations link somewhere and come to this page, on page load, i want the URl to appended as follows on the fly? The Hospital is a checkbox on the page which needs to be checked by default. So when they land on the page, they see all the hospitals instead of having to check the hospital check box and reload the page. Is this possible using jquery?

http://mysite.com/locations.aspx?k=("Hospital")

```
Find locations by&#160;<input name="Keyword" type="text" size="70"/><input name="Search" type="submit" value="Search"/><br/><br/>

Hospitals<input name="Hospitals" type="checkbox" value="Hospital"/> &#160; 
Offices<input name="Office" type="checkbox" value="Office"/> &#160; 
Emergency Centers<input name="EmergencyCenters" type="checkbox" value="Emergency"/>&#160; 
Out-Patient Centers<input name="Out-Patient" type="checkbox" value="Out-Patient"/>&#160; 
Facilities<input name="Facility" type="checkbox" value="Facility"/>
```

Comment: I understand I can have the HREF value of "Locations" link as http://mysite.com/locations.aspx?k=("Hospital") and have the hospitals checked = true.. I wonder if there is any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create (inside the page http://mysite.com/locations.aspx ) a function like:

```
function getDefault() {
var trail = '?k=("Hospital")';
var url = "http://mysite.com/locations.aspx" + trail;
window.location = url;
}
```

and add `onload` to the `<body>` tag like

```
<body onload="getDefault();">
```

of course, it will reload the page (without user intervention) but with the new trailing parameter.

... as for the check box, you can add the proper attribute

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name=Hospitals]").attr('checked','checked');
}); //  ready
```

and it will be checked on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

In newer browsers you can use the [HTML5 history api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate) to change the url without a page reload, however, older browsers that don't support it will require a page reload.