# Is it possible to avoid the form action url from getting appended to the url in the address bar.? Or how can i remove finally?

Tags: jsp, url, servlets

Is it possible to avoid the form action url from getting appended to the url in the address bar.?
Or how can i remove it in the end?
Ex : 
1) Landing page url : abc.net. Its a JSP page. Clicked a button on this page.
2) Lands into another JSP page containing fields along with SUBMIT and CANCEL.
3) On clicking submit in this page,through a form action url specified, a servlet gets called and
 
  url gets changed to abc.net/submit_click_action.
    In this servlet, after processing, through the RequestDispatcher, i am making another servlet call,which gets me back to the landing JSP page.
  But the url that i see in the address bar is :    abc.net/submit_click_action.
    Is there a way to avoid adding that 'submit_click_action' being appended to the address bar?
    Or how can i remove it in the end?
    I read about Pushstates in here: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968663/is-it-possible-to-change-change-the-url-in-address-bar-or-browser-on-certain-eve).
    I am not sure if i need to use this.
 
    Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forward and a redirect are different things. And what is displayed in the URL bar of the browser is the last request that the browser has sent to server.

What happened :

- you clicked on a submit button and brownser posted the form to an URL
- in the servlet processing the request, you forwarded to another page - the browser was not notified of that

=> that's the reason why the URL bar still display the action URL

You should have done a redirect to the URL of the destination page. It is called the [Post-Redirect-Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern :

- the displayed URL is the correct one allowing the user to bookmark the page
- if user clicks on the browser back button, he will never receive the ugly message *"Do you really want to send again ...?"* : because of the redirect, the POST has been replaced in browser history

Comment: Thanks! I was searching around for removing the part from the url. Didnt realise

Answer (score 0):

A successful POST request should *redirect* to another URL. It shouldn't *forward* to another servlet. This allows the user to safely bookmark or refresh the page: the displayed URL in the address bar will be the page obtained by the redirect, using GET.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Thanks! I was searching around for removing the action url part from the url. Didnt realise it had something to do with Post-Redirect-Get.