# How to track user hits back button on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want to track event which fire on, when user hits back button on the browser.
I found many post related this but all suggest use of `.onbeforeunload` event. but this event also fire on, when page is refresh or browser window is closed.

If there is any idea to track only browser back event.
Thanks for your help...!!!

Comment: You should give a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate

Comment: There isn't any way you can tell specifically for when the back button is pressed. Why do you need this functionality? Maybe we could suggest a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but @gustavohenke, Can i do it with jquery? because i don't use HTML 5.

Comment: @dhsto, I want to prevent user to go back on previous.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, my question is same as yous question but i want to do my task using jquery or java script

Comment: @IshanJain — Every answer to that question uses JavaScript. (And jQuery is a JS library, not an alternative to JS).

Answer (score 1):

You can use History.js:
http://balupton.github.io/history.js/demo/

> History.js gracefully supports the HTML5 History/State APIs
>   (pushState, replaceState, onPopState) in all browsers