# HTML5 history pushState is not working

Tags: javascript

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but this small bit of code does not work:

```
window.history.pushState("foo", "foo", "foo");
```

It will generate the following error in **firefox *29***:

```
TypeError: window.history.pushState is not a function
```

Comment: did you have a look [Here?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: What browser are you using when you get this error? Check it if your browser [supports the history api](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history).

Comment: @complex857 The browser is (as mentioned in the post): firefox 29

Comment: @Banana Yes, mozilla docs are usually my first stop

Comment: oh, looks like i can't read (-:

Comment: @nablex which release of the firefoxes is that? firefox/firefox aurora/firefox beta/firefox for organizations ?

Comment: @nablex i have tried your code in firefox 29.0 and it works fine, are you redefining `window` / `history` / `pushState` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Banana Yes, I have done it from scratch and that seems to be the problem, one of the scripts i was including defined a variable "var history". Out of curiosity: why is "window.history" overwritten by "var history"? Are all vars by default in window scope?

Comment: @nablex yes they are. variables that you define directly under a script tag are in the window scope. you can try it, open developer console anywhere and define `var banana=2;`, and then type in `window.banana` and you will receive 2

Comment: Nice to know :) Could you add it as an answer? Then I can accept it.

Comment: @nablex you can add an answer yourself and accept it. Then there is no need to read all the comments to understand that this issue is solved already.

Comment: Hope it will help. Refer balupton's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently one of the scripts I included had a declaration:

```
var history = ...;
```

Unbeknownst to me, all vars on the root actually live in the window scope so the custom history var actually overwrote the original window.history.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as

Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

It should work as per Mozzila.

Please find more On [Mozilla Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)