# The meaning of History object (pushState, popState, ReplaceState) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, history, back, pushstate, popstate

I want to get knowledge about ***History object*** in JavaScript(also History.pushState, History.PopState , ...) . but except the following link,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Also this link:
http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

I couldnt find anything comprehensive specially in **examples** and **usages**. 
Could any one help me about that?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate and http://jsfiddle.net/fJ9wq/