# Browser not scrolling to anchor on back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a site that allows you to search for images. I wrote a simple script for infinite scrolling, but had an issue with using the browser's back button. Basically, if you scrolled down a lot and infinite scrolling was loading new "pages" of images, then you clicked on one of the images, then hit back to go back to the search results, you'd be back at the 1st page of results. To get back to where you were, you'd have to scroll through all of those "pages" you've already scrolled through.

I attempted to solve this by updating the browser history when you click on an image.  When you click on an image, it sets the history to search/page_num#image_id.  That way when you hit back, it takes you right to the page you were on and should scroll to the image.

The URL gets properly set in browser history.  And if I manually type in that URL, the browser loads the right page number and scrolls to the right image.  But when I try to use it in a real life scenario (searching, scrolling, clicking an image, hitting back to get back to the results), the browser doesn't scroll to the image anchor.

Anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript is stateless. The browser has no idea where you left off unless you explicitly store it and tell it where to resume

Comment: I am telling it where to resume.  Think about it like this: Imagine you had a webpage with an anchor tag on it like this: <a name="scroll_here">.   You could send someone a link: mydomain.com/#scroll_here and they would get scrolled to that anchor.  That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I set the URL to include that anchor that I want it to scroll to. But it isn't scrolling to it when you hit back to that page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use window.history in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528432/how-do-i-use-window-history-in-javascript)

Comment: @TinyGiant That answer does not answer my question at all.

Comment: Well then your question is lacking a [mcve], which is required for debugging questions.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think you didn't read it completely. My question is not about how to use window.history. I've got that down. The question is about how to over ride the browser's attempts to scroll to where it wants

Comment: Your question describes a problem with your code, yet you have not included any code. Without code, your question is off-topic.