# cordova inappbrowser plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, inappbrowser

I have a Vue Js app, and I am using Cordova for wrapping it into android application.

the app contains 2 pages, `landing page` which contains items, and `details page` which shows details about an item. when you click on an item on `landing page`, the `details page` appears.

I have a `button` on the `details page`, when clicking it, it goes to another`component`, and this `component` on `mounted()` event, it displays a html content from the local storage of the phone using `inappbrowser` plugin from Cordova.

the problem is, after the `inappbrowser` shows the contents, if I press the back button of the phone, it redirects me to the `details page`, then if I press the back button of the phone again, it redirects me to the `inappbrowser`! instead of the `landing page`. and if I press it again, it will redirect me to the `details page`, then if I press the back button again, it will show the `innappbrowser` and so on....

here is the code of the `component` which on `mounted()` event, it shows the `innappbrowser`

```
<template>
  <div>      
      <h1>Loading >></h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

export default 
{
  mounted()
  {
     Vue.cordova.on("deviceReady", () => {
        var ref = window.open('file:///storage/emulated/0/tin/story.html', '_self');
     });
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I tried to add the `hardwareback=no` to the options of `inappbrowser` but it didn't work.

what should I do to remove the `inappbrowser` from the stack history when pressing the back button.

Comment: note: `hardwareback` is to define if user can navigate through inappbrowser history (not the app one) on back button. You should have what you need in  `window.history` states or the `"backbutton"` event.

Comment: @Kaddath thanks, how should I do it ?

Comment: never did it with cordova and inappbrowser, so i cannot give you the exact way. You can try to log the event object in `window.onpopstate` [see explanations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528432/how-do-i-use-window-history-in-javascript) and `backbutton` event to see what you get and what to do with it..