# a href does not load the new page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I have an `<a href="/other-page">` that when I click on it changes the address bar to `mysite.com/other-page` but does not load it...

I need to do right-click and then *open the link in new tab* in order to really open the desired page.

I thought that is a bug of Chrome, but I tested in IE(11) and it behaves similarly...

What could be the cause of this "strange" behavior?

**PS.** I don't use (at least, intentionally) and don't want to use, *any browser history manipulations*. I just need to classically open a simple link in the same page, it's all I need!

Comment: Do you have a single page applicaton? A static page? More context please, there could be an issue with the location headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good tutorial for using HTML5 History API (Pushstate?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate)

Comment: The "the **concrete** similar online **link** behavior for question" is using the history API as I just linked

Comment: why do you think is using history API? I don't need to use any history manipulations

Comment: "why do you think is using history API" because that is how it works...  "I don't need to use any history manipulations" In that case your "**concrete** similar online **link** behavior for question" sucks

Comment: The only information you have provided is a external link. Which is the only thing we can go by. And I just gave the the solution of said link. If that is not what you want there is no way for anybody to be able to help you solve your problem with the information included in the question

Comment: The provided link should be fixed. But I didn't find any solution in the "duplicate" post, nor in the provided link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API, because *I don't see any `window.history` usage* in the page I linked in the OP

Comment: @PeeHaa: I found the problem: this is because of the `position:fixed` and the `z-index: 1` of the container... so nothing to do with History API

Comment: This question is improperly tagged as JavaScript. Correctly tagging it as `html` will lead to more views from people with the same issue and more upvotes in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem was because of the `position:fixed` and the `z-index: 1` of the container...

The absolute or fixed positions could combined with the z-index > 0 could cause this kind of problems.

As I didn't want to change the display position of the container, my solution was to "hack" the href behavior:

```
<a href="/myurl" onclick="parent.location='/myurl'; return false;">
    show more...
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the attribute in the anchor tag `target="_blank".`

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://your_url_here.html">Link</a>
```

Remove `target="_blank` then open same tap

Comment: there is any target attribute on my link... I don't need to open it in a new tab

Comment: am not sure but i will try sir @Serge