# Nonstop onchange when page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a script that appends strings to the url when (1) the page is loading and (2) when onchange is invoked. The problem is the browser keeps on triggering the change event nonstop. How do I make it to trigger once when the page is loaded?

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#staff-list").on('change', function() {
        location.href = "?account=" + $(this).val();
      }).triggerHandler('change');
    });
  </script>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-addon gi data-gi-size gi-user-add"></span>
    <select id="staff-list" name="staff-list">
       <Option>1</Option>
       <Option>2</Option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please share some markup.

Comment: You make infinite function call by `.triggerHandler('change')` on `change` event

Comment: Changing `location.href` will reload the page, which then causes the whole cycle to restart: set ready handler, set change handler, invoke change handler -> reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a condition in if statement to stop the infinite redirect loop.. try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#staff-list").on('change', function() {
      var AddToUrl = "?account="+ $(this).val();
      if(window.location.href.indexOf(AddToUrl) == -1) {
       window.location.href = AddToUrl;
      }
     }).change();
  });
</script>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-addon gi data-gi-size gi-user-add"></span>
    <select id="staff-list" name="staff-list">
       <Option>1</Option>
       <Option>2</Option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool..it works. Thanks, Mohamed. I'll accept your answer. I also noticed that the page is refreshing/reloading. How do we make it without page reloading?

Comment: @ubuntujavy Without page reloading .. you will need to work with history API .. to `pushState` / `replaceState`  you can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API  .. and you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4843248/3385827

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `triggerHandler('change')`

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#staff-list").on('change', function() {
        location.href = "?account=" + $(this).val();
      });
    });
  </script>
```

This is causing the infinite looping.

**Update**
You can put some recursion exit condition. That is passing an extra parameter to the `location.href` and don't fire `triggerHandler` if the parameter is there.

Comment: Thanks. I also need it to append when the page is loading. How do I do that?