# How to redirect WordPress visitors to new URL when they close or click back button

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect users when they attempting to close or click back button. Is it possible to catch this kind of action with a script?

Comment: Why?  This is almost always a terrible user experience.  If the user hits back, it shouldn't be prevented without a great reason (like going back would lose data they care about).

Comment: @Mason, IMHO, the "why" is tangential, the meat of the matter is on the "how" :)

Comment: Of interest: [Good tutorial for using HTML5 History API (Pushstate?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015613/1287812)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is essentially a browser security restriction. All you can really tell is if the user navigates away from the page (`onbeforeunload`, `onunload` fire) but you can't tell where they went unless you've set up your page to allow it.

HTML5 has introduced the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API); in modern browsers that is, the `onpopstate` event will fire if the user navigates back to an earlier "page" on your site. [Here's a great doc page](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/) regarding the history API.

Alternatively, there is a method which has been introduced in using some JavaScript. You can utilize `location.hash` and when the respective value changes by a user (for example by clicking back), redirect the user to whichever page you'd like.

Comment: can you please guide me step by step for wordpress cms

Comment: It's not as simple unfortunately; a handful of JavaScript will need to be implemented which works with the pushState function. You can then set your own event handler to redirect your users to the page you'd like them to.