Cloudflare Pages Static Website Hosting Route All Paths to Index.html
I am using Cloudflare Pages to host a javascript app that will use HTML5 pushStates. The problem is if the user bookmarks any of the URLs, it will not resolve to anything. What I need is the ability to take all url requests and serve up the root index.html rather than just doing a full redirect. Then my javascript application could parse the URL and serve the proper page.
Is there any way to tell Cloudflare Pages to serve the index.html for all URL requests instead of doing redirects? This would be similar to setting up apache to handle all incoming requests by serving up a single index.html as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647521/1762614.
(I am hosting a static Flutter website, if that helps with anything. Also, a similar question was posted, only about Amazon S3 here)
Thank you so much in advance for all of your help!
